# How to calculate large nPr in C?

Tags: c

I have written a function to calculate the nPr of two numbers in C, can you please help me adapt it to handle large numbers?

I need to be able to calculate a value of upto 1x10^12 - I have tried many different data types and am very stuck!

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>

int main()
    {
        long int n=49,k=6;
            printf("%li nPr %li = %li\n\n",n,k,nPr(n,k));

        return 0;

    }      

long nPr(long int n, long int k);
     long nPr(long int n, long int k){

        if (n < 0 ){
            printf("\nERROR - n is less than 0\n\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (k > n ){
            printf("\nERROR - k is greater than n\n\n");
            return -1;
        }

        else {
            long int i,result = 1,c=n+1-k;

            for(i=c; i<=n; i++)
            {
                result = result * i;
            }
            return result;
        }
     }
```

Thanks

J

**UPDATE:** These are permutations WITHOUT repition,

also I tried

```
long long nPr(long long int n, long long int k);
long long nPr(long long int n, long long int k){

    if (n < 0 ){
        printf("\nERROR - n is less than 0\n\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (k > n ){
        printf("\nERROR - k is greater than n\n\n");
        return -1;
    }

    else {
        long long int i,result = 1,c=n+1-k;

        for(i=c; i<=n; i++)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }
        return result;
    }
 }
```

however it did not seem to make any difference

Comment: i think it's number of permutations.

Comment: @SethCarnegie No, [permutation with repetition.](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)

Comment: Btw, @OP: what about using a bignum library?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you try "long long" for 64-bit number?

Comment: permutations are without repition, using GNU GCC compiler, long long had no effect if I used it correctly (showed how I tried to change it in above edit)

Comment: You don't need to calculate the factorials fully to calculate npr/ncr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311984/permutation-and-combination-in-c-sharp/26312275#26312275

Answer (score 4):

You may want to compute using [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), perhaps using the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) library. If you switch to C++, you could use the familiar `a+b` notation even for bignums, using [the C++ class interface to GMP](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html). If you stay in pure C, you'll need to carefully use specific routines, e.g. [mpz_add](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Arithmetic.html) for addition.

BTW, some languages (e.g. [Common Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp)) natively support bignums (without the need to modify the source code working on ordinary numbers). You might want to try with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) (at least on Linux).

Of course, bignum arithmetic (a very complex subject) is slower than native arithmetic.

Bignums are not supported natively in C, you need to use a library (or implement itself yours, which is a non-sense: good algorithms for bignums are hard to understand and to implement, so better use an existing library).

PS. `long long` won't really help, since it is still 64 bits. Some GCC compilers and target processors may support [__int128](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) i.e. 128 bits integers, but you really need bignums.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fully evaluate the factorials when dividing, this reduces the risk of integer overflow (as well as being more efficient):

```
long factorialDivision(int topFactorial, int divisorFactorial)
{
    long result = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = topFactorial; i > divisorFactorial; i--)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}

long factorial(int i)
{
    if (i <= 1)
        return 1;
    return i * factorial(i - 1);
}

long nPr(int n, int r)
{
    // naive: return factorial(n) / factorial(n - r);
    return factorialDivision(n, n - r);
}

long nCr(int n, int r)
{
    // naive: return factorial(n) / factorial(r) * factorial(n - r);
    return nPr(n, r) / factorial(r);
}
```