# Permutation and Combination in C#

Tags: c#, math

Please tell me how can I apply permutation and combination in C# console application and take values of N and r and calculate permutation and combination.

Comment: You just need the number of nCr and nPr? Have you tried anything yet? post it and tell where you are stuck.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just had a go doing this for fun, it's actually a little challenging as a naive implementation overflows `long` very quickly. I've included those in comments.

## Equations

```
nPr = n! / (n - r)!
nCr = n! / r! (n - r)!
```

## Implementaion

```
public static class PermutationsAndCombinations
{
    public static long nCr(int n, int r)
    {
        // naive: return Factorial(n) / (Factorial(r) * Factorial(n - r));
        return nPr(n, r) / Factorial(r);
    }

    public static long nPr(int n, int r)
    {
        // naive: return Factorial(n) / Factorial(n - r);
        return FactorialDivision(n, n - r);
    }

    private static long FactorialDivision(int topFactorial, int divisorFactorial)
    {
        long result = 1;
        for (int i = topFactorial; i > divisorFactorial; i--)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }

    private static long Factorial(int i)
    {
        if (i <= 1)
            return 1;
        return i * Factorial(i - 1);
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
Console.WriteLine(PermutationsAndCombinations.nPr(10, 3));
Console.WriteLine(PermutationsAndCombinations.nCr(10, 3));
```

Prints:

```
720
120
```

Comment: @Richard, no this is not the naive one I speak of, that would be `Factorial(n) / Factorial(n - r)`, will update to make clearer

Comment: Got it ! Sorry, it's also my fault, english is not my mother language.

Comment: // naive: return Factorial(n) / Factorial(r) * Factorial(n - r);

should be   // naive: return Factorial(n) / (Factorial(r) * Factorial(n - r));

Comment: Solution with FactorialDivision give false results. "Naive" solution is slower, but give correct results.

Comment: @bmi please give me example values you see wrong values for

Comment: Look here http://rosalind.info/problems/sset/solutions/?sort=date   at solution of MissHellsFather. There is used "naive" version, because FactorialDivision version gave bad result.

Comment: I'm not signing up for some random website to see what you are talking about.

Why can't you just give me an example pair of numbers that exhibit a failure? e.g. npr(100, 200)

Did you know for high numbers, naive will be wrong due to long overflow: I don't expect naive to work with numbers above 20.

Comment: This code gave me bad result before:

`        int n = 985;
        BigInteger outp = 1; // for 0 combination

        // sum combinations count of all sizes
        for (int r = 1; r <= n; r++)
            outp += nCr(n, r);

        var result = outp % 1000000; // result is here
`
I tested it again now and it look it's good now. May be some mistake after modify for BigInteger - I'm not sure now.

Comment: Good to hear. Because mathematically speaking the factorial devision is sound. Terms on top and bottom just cancel each other out, e.g.: 5!/3! = 5x4x3x2x1/3x2x1 = 5x4