# C# Equivalent to Python's Math.Comb function

Tags: c#, combinatorics

Is there a C# equivalent function to Python's Math.Comb function?

I currently do not see anything in the System.Math class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permutation and Combination in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311984/permutation-and-combination-in-c-sharp)

Comment: also: [seems reasonably easy to implement yourself](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-math-comb-method/)

Comment: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Combinatorics.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in the .NET Framework.

It's easy to code it if you need just that one.

Otherwise I recommend you to use Math.NET Numerics library, look at [this page](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Combinatorics.htm#Combinations) for combinatory:

> double Combinations(int n, int k)
>
> Count the number of possible
>   combinations without repetition. The order does not matter and each
>   object can be chosen only once.